# Getting Component by name and JTextComponent

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, jcomponent, jtextcomponent

I have jTextField named "startTextBox1"

And i use below methods can call it by name;

Creating Hashmap in class.

```
private HashMap componentMap;
```

Fill hashmap with components name.

```
private void createComponentMap() {
    componentMap = new HashMap<String,Component>();
    Component[] components = jDesktopPane1.getComponents();
    for (int i=0; i < components.length; i++) {
            componentMap.put(components[i].getName(), components[i]);
    }
}
```

For call components by their names.

```
public JComponent getComponentByName(String name) {
    if (componentMap.containsKey(name)) {
            return (JComponent) componentMap.get(name);
    }
    else return null;
}
```

When i call `getComponentByName("startTextBox1").getName()` it gives me startTextBox1 succesfully.

But i can't call `getComponentByName("startTextBox1").getText()` because mapped component is JComponent and `getName()` is JComponent method. But `getText()` is JTextComponent object.

How can i get text from my textfield in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
public String getTextByComponentName(String name) {
    if (componentMap.containsKey(name)) {
            JComponent comp = (JComponent) componentMap.get(name);
            if (comp instanceof JTextComponent) {
                  return ((JTextComponent)comp).getText();
            }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Possible and probably solve the current issue. Any generic way for solve it? I mean not create method for every type.

Comment: i implement it to my code. But when i call this method i cant type .getText() it generate compile error. But first mentioned specific type calling method succesfully working fyi.